# Class of Data and how to do some data manipulation in R

Tags: r

I have a subset of a genetic dataset in which I want to run some correlations between the CpG markers.
I have inspected the *class*, class(data) of this subset and it shows that it's a
[1] "matrix" "array"

The structure str(data) also shows an output of the form

num [1:64881, 1:704] 0.0149 NA 0.0558 NA NA ...
-- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : chr [1:64881] "cg11223003" NA "cg22629907" NA ...
..$ : chr [1:704] "200357150075_R01C01" "200357150075_R02C01" "200357150075_R03C01" "200357150075_R04C01" ...

It actually looks as though it were a data frame but the class of the variable tells otherwise. It's kind of confusing.
I need help on how to manipulate the dataset to obtain a matrix or data frame format of the markers to enable run the correlations.

Comment: Why would it not work ? If data is of matrix class then it should be ok. otherwise you can try to convert `dat` to `as.data.frame(data)` if you really need a dataframe

Comment: Alright, thank you.